# Fetching telemetry from DJI N3, while RC is in control?

Tags: dji-sdk

I have a DJI N3, that uses Lightbridge as the remote controller (RC) and a Raspberry Pi as the onboard computer. Is it possible to collect N3 telemetry on the Pi, while the N3 is being controlled by the Lightbridge?

I am new to OSDK. My understanding is that it isn't possible because the Raspberry Pi does not run unless the RC is not found. This is because the Control precedence order is as follows: RC, Mobile, OSDK.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,you can run telemetry in the pi because "telemtery" function didn't control the drone and just get the data from the drone.SO the RC will not affect this function.
[image]